# Ignoring specific files in Dockerfile.dockerignore does not work

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerignore

**Here is my issue**: I want to include/exclude specific file when building a service called `django`. But when playing with `Dockerfile.dockerignore` file, I do not succeed what I want and I can't figure out which syntax to adopt in order to do so.

**Repo structure is the following**:

```sh
.
└── root_dir
    ├── django
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── Dockerfile.ignore
    │   └── stuff
    ├── documentation
    │   └── stuff
    ├── useless dir
    └── another useless dir
```

My `docker-compose.yml` used to make the build is the following:

```yaml
version: '3.5'

services:

  [...]

  django:
    build:
      context: $ROOT_DIR
      dockerfile: $ROOT_DIR/django/Dockerfile

  [...]
```

As you can see, context is `root_dir` and not `django` (because I need to copy a few things from `documentation` dir at build time).

**What I need when building my image**:

- django rep
- documentation rep

**What I want to ignore when building my image**:

- everything but `django` and `documentation` dirs
- Dockerfile and Dockerfile.dockerignore
- and a few other things (virtual env, `*.pyc` etc, but we'll stick with `Dockerfile` and `Dockerfile.dockerignore` for that question!)

What my `Dockerfile.dockerignore` looks like in order to do so:

```yaml
# Ignore everything
*

# Allows django and documentation rep (context is root of project)
!/django
!/documentation

# Ignoring some files
**/Dockerfile
**/Dockerfile.dockerignore
```

but my issue is that the files I want to ignore are still present in my image! And this is not good for me. I think I tried any syntax possible (`**/`, `*/*/...`...) but I can't find one that suits my need.

Many thanks if you can help me with that!

EDIT: for those wondering about that `Dockerfile.dockerignore` file, you can have a look here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file

Comment: Late to the party but did you trying building the image after enabling BuildKit for building ?
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds

Answer (score 1):

Running this command before the 'docker build' fixed it for me:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

FYI: I did *not* need to install 'buildkit' first.

Comment: I had this issue! my webstorm didn't have the buildkit option toggled on for docker builds in the run configuration... spend about an hour on this

Answer (score 0):

Docker ignore file name should be **.dockerignore**
You can check the documentation here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Comment: No actually at build time Docker first looks for a `<Dockerfile_name>.dockerignore` file before looking for a `.dockerignore`. In my case, because of the `dockerfile` line in my `docker-compose.yml` file, `Dockerfile` name is `$ROOT_DIR/django/Dockerfile`. A single `.dockerignore` file would be ok if located at the root of my project, which is not what I am trying to do.
Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#use-a-dockerignore-file

Comment: That documentation says "when using the Buildkit backend", as @Devansh Sharma pointed out

Answer (score 0):

**Enable BuildKit...**
I had the same confusion; none of my `*.dockerignore` files seemed to be working:

```bash
$ tree 
...
├── development
│   ├── Dev.Dockerfile
│   ├── Dev.Dockerfile.dockerignore
│   ├── docker-compose.dev.yml
│   ├── docker-compose.prod.yml
│   ├── notas-de-desarrollo.md
│   ├── Prod.Dockerfile
│   └── Prod.Dockerfile.dockerignore
└── README.md
...
```

However, as @Matthias and @user2270347 pointed out, all we need to do is enable the "new" Buildx. For me and my Arch, I just had to install it with `sudo pacman -S docker-buildx`.